# Configure a Wacom tablet on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wacom

I used my tablet (Wacom Cintiq 13HD) on (K)Ubuntu 14.04 where I had a nice dialogue under *System Settings → Input Devices → Wacom Tablet*. This allowed me to map commands to the buttons on the tablet, create different profiles of commands and determine which are of the monitors the stylus maps to. However, on 16.04 this options is gone. Is there a way to get it back?

If it can't be brought back, how can I still configure my graphics tablet, i.e. map commands to the buttons, map the screen area (for the cursor), etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a script to map the buttons and screen area on my Wacom Cintiq 13HD. Basically This is a collection of calls to `xsetwacom` specific to the tablet.

This is the script (`~/.local/bin/wacomagic.sh`) that I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Settings for tablet on the right side of the main monitor.
# Tablet dimensions are 1920x1080, main monitor is 2880x1620
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pen stylus" MapToOutput "1920x1080+2880+0"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pen eraser" MapToOutput "1920x1080+2880+0"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" MapToOutput "1920x1080+2880+0"

# Settings for buttons
# Note that the buttons numbers 4-7 are reserved by XInput
# (source: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_Configuration Tip in "Pad" section)
# so the buttons just up to 13.
# This is the mapping for the Cintiq 13HD
#
#     +----+
#     |  2 |
#     +----+
#     |  3 |
#  +--+----+--+
#  |    11    |
#+-+--+----+--+-+
#| 12 |  1 | 10 |
#+-+--+----+--+-+
#  |    13    |
#  +--+----+--+
#     |  8 |
#     +----+
#     |  9 |
#     +----+

# shift and control
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 2 "key Shift_L"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 3 "key Control_L"

# brush sizes and zoom and mirroring
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 1 "key m"  # mirror canvas in krita
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 10 "key +ctrl +shift + -shift -ctrl"  # Custom key for [increase brush size] (krita)
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 11 "key +"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 12 "key +ctrl +shift - -shift -ctrl"  # Custom key for [decrease brush size] (krita)
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 13 "key -"

# undo and redo
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 8 "key +ctrl z -ctrl"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 13HD Pad pad" Button 9 "key +ctrl +shift z -shift -ctrl"
```

I created an application launcher that runs the wacomagic script and added it to a panel on the right side of the tablet in the topmost spot. This ensures that I can click it using the stylus even before the mapping commands (on top of the file) have been run.

The commands I map to the buttons are for my personal workflow. If you would like to have different (sets of) commands mapped you can just create one script per set.

**Edit:** For newer versions of (K)ubuntu this might not be required and work out of the box. Consult the [awesome guides of David Revoy](https://www.davidrevoy.com/article783/kubuntu-linux-20-04-for-a-digital-painting-workstation-reasons-and-install-guide).